# Access subroutine inside a module using a linked library

Tags: fortran, static-libraries

I would like to use a subroutine written inside a static library (written in Fortran) inside a different Fortran executables.
This is my working example:

```
subroutine my(a,b,c)
    implicit none
    real*8, intent(in)  :: a,b
    real*8, intent(out) :: c
    !
    c = a + b
    !
end subroutine
```

That generates a XXX.lib file that I am pointing at with this main:

```
program main
    implicit none
    !
    real*8 :: var1, var2
    real*8 :: out1
    !
    var1 = 15.0
    var2 = 10.0
    call mysum(var1,var2,out1)
    !
    write(*,*) out1
    !
end program
```

Everything is working, but the problem arise when I want to have my subroutine defined inside a module, like this:

```
module mymodule
contains
    !
    subroutine mysum(a,b,c)
        implicit none
        real*8, intent(in)  :: a,b
        real*8, intent(out) :: c
        !
        c = a + b
        !
    end subroutine
end module
```

At this point the "main" compiler fails in finding the  subroutine. Is there a way to let the compiler "see" the subroutine declared inside the module?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, if you have a subroutine (or anything else) defined in a module that you want to be made accessible somewhere else you need to "use" that module:

```
program main
  use mymodule
  implicit none
  ....
end program
```

When you don't have that `use mymodule` which allows the compiler to see that the subroutine `mysum` is actually a module subroutine, the compiler is going to treat `mysum` still as an external subroutine.

Previously, `mysum` was an external subroutine, but that external subroutine was defined in the library object.  It no longer is in the same way: there will likely be various bits of *name mangling*.  It's your linker complaining.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that "use mymodule" was not necessary in this case, since it's inside a library. This actually solves my issue, thanks!